# C++ constructor inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

Let's say we have a base class Country, which has country letter as a variable. Each derived class should have it's own country letter. I tried this but it obviously doesn't work:

```
class Country
{
protected:
    char letter;
    virtual void set_letter(){}
public:
    Country()
    {
        set_letter();
    }
};

class England : public Country
{
    void set_letter()
    {
        letter = 'e';
    }
};
```

My idea was that derived classes would inherit the constructor of base class which would call the "set_letter()" method which would be different for every class. But now I know it isn't possible because the constructor will call the method from base class and not from derived.

The other option is to write "letter = 'e';" in every constructor definition body. But what if a class has many constructors? I would have to write it every time.

I hope you understand what I'm talking about. What is the best solution for this? Maybe this:

```
class Country
{
protected:
    virtual char letter() const = 0;
    .
    .
    .
};

class England : public Country
{
    static const char let = 'e';
    char letter() const
    {
        return let;
    }
    .
    .
    .
};
```

Yeah, it works. But I want to know is there a way of doing it without making "letter" a method. Don't ask why... thanks

Comment: protected ctor in `Country` which takes the country `char` as argument.

Comment: The problem is that `Country` is created before `England`, that's why you cannot rely on base constructor calling some derived function. Instead, reverse the logic, let the derived class do all the work (ie: `Country(char l) : letter(l) {} ` and `England() : Country('e') {}`).

Comment: That way I would have to write every constructor with initialisation?
England() : Country('e'){...}
England(int a) : Country('e'){...}
England(const char* c) : Country('e'){...}

Comment: `template <char letter> class Country ...`

Comment: If you don't use templates, you could use a private static data member in the derived class (like in your proposed solution) and pass its value to `Country`'s ctor.

Comment: @n.m. thats exactly what I have answered just now

Comment: Another solution, which could be argued to be better OOP, would be to not have a data member at all, and instead just define a member function for each sub class along the lines of `char get_letter() const { return 'e';}` and make it pure virtual in the base class. It always seems a little bit suspicious to have a data member which essentially does nothing but identify the type of subclass - which the type of the subclass obviously does by itself - and to have a data member in the parent which does little other than identify the sub class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try another solution: **Use templates**

```
template<char LETTER>
class Country
{
private:
    static const char letter = LETTER;

public:
    char get_letter() const { return letter; }
};


class England : public Country<'e'> { ... };
class Spain   : public Country<'s'> { ... };
class France  : public Country<'f'> { ... };
/* etc */
```

Comment: @tuks Note this solution is more correct in a formal sense: You are representing countries with classes, so the letter is linked/relationed within the class, not the instances of the class. Because of that, its better to specify the letter in the class declaration (through templates in this case) instead of through constructors (Initializating class-scope things through object initializators (constructors) is not a good practice I think).

Comment: One has to wonder about the geopolitical implications of instanciating several instances of a country... :o)

Comment: lol :D I made up this example because I have something similar for my homework... and, yeah, Manu, I agree, I really like this solution, I think it's perfect... just hope that my professor thinks that too :)

Comment: @tuks Thats another problem :) I suggest you a title for the question about that problem: ***Does my teacher really knows C++?*** Short answer: Probably not

Comment: haha, he is a famous programming professor in our country, but I'm just wondering will he accept the solution because he didn't teach us that way :)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to get rid of the letter member and get the country code using a (virtual) get method. Using this approach, you may get the country code only using the get method.
This has the added benefit of saving (little) memory for each instance, and the disadvantage of having a virtual method call. 
Yet another variant would be to declare the get method in the base class as pure virtual - hence forcing implementation of it in derived classes, while prohibiting instantiation of the base class.

```
class Country
{
protected:
public:
    Country() {};
    // you may alternatively use "virtual char get_letter() = 0;" instead - 
    //     forcing you to implement get_letter() in every derived class, 
    //     while preventing direct use of the base class.
    virtual char get_letter()
    { 
         return((char)0); // 0 being code for generic Country instance
    }
 }

class England : public Country
{
    char get_letter()
    {
        return('e');
    }
};
```